# How to resume Git-Flow after a break cause by a merge conflict on a finish command?

Tags: git, git-flow

Do i really need to complete all the step by hand every time I "Finish" a branch and there is a conflict merging it with Git-Flow?  Or there's a way to resume after all the conflict are solved?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After resolving the conflict, you simply call

```
git flow release finish [RELEASE_NAME]
```

again.
git is 'smart' in that if you try to do merge from branch A to branch B more than once, the second and subsequent times are ignored with "Already up-to-date" as long as the source of the merge has not changed.

Comment: I don't think that it works because to just call "git flow finish" after resolving conflicts because when you finish something as an example and you have conflicts, you will have to resolve conflicts and then do a commit. After that and ONLY after that you will be able to continue the process. In my case, I prefer to do a finish because it will delete both the remote and the local branch where if you want to do the same process manually, you will have to do two distinct operations for the same result. I found this solution after searching in the source code of the git-flow project.

Comment: Git-flow is enough smart to just continue where he left when you do a finish command twice because of conflict.

Comment: yes, after resolving the conflict and commit, even at the master branch, just re-run the `git flow release finish [RELEASE_NAME]`, the first merge will be jumped, because the conflict is resolved and then release commit and then merge.